# Unable to change an Active Directory user account from a Windows 10 laptop

Tags: windows-10, passwords, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-domain

When any users tries to change their password, the following error message appears
"the security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship"
The laptop can see the domain. Users can log in and out.

Steps to try and resolve this so far:

1. Remove Computer from the domain. Rejoin laptop to the domain.
2. Remove the computer account from the domain, then remove the computer from the domain, join the computer to the domain.

The domain functional level is Windows server 2008.
Forrest functional level is Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Do you have more than one DC?

Comment: Hi Tim. Yes there is more than one DC.

Comment: I have this problem occasionally. With 60+ DCs in my domain, i almost have to wait a whole day before i can rejoin.
That being said, be sure to wait until the deletion/break has reached all DCs.

I cannot guarantee that is the fix, but a good place to start.

Comment: I have tried this on a different domain and it works, this looks to be domain specific.